Is there an established way to model this PIR + JFET circuit?
Pictured is a PIR (passive infra-red) sensor hooked up to a JFET.

The diagram is from these design notes, which describes the workings of the PIR sensor as:
The PIR motion sensor consists of two or more elements that output a voltage proportional to the amount of
incident infrared radiation. Each pair of pyroelectric elements are connected in series such that if the
voltage generated by each element is equal, as in the case of IR due to ambient room temperature or no
motion, then the overall voltage of the sensor elements is 0 V.

The circuit looks like a self-biasing JFET, which helps to understand what the mathematical relationship between the resistors, Vcc, and current might be. However, the self-biasing configuration doesn't have a voltage source at the gate, whereas this one does (the PIR).
Is there an established way to model circuits such as this? What I mean by that is, is there an equation which relates Vcc, the value of the resistors, and the voltage at the output of the pyro-electric element to the current flowing out of the JFET?

where did you get the diagram? ... please update your post with a link

@MrGerber - https://www.tij.co.jp/jp/lit/ug/tiduda8/tiduda8.pdf works for me

@Greenonline an edit was made to fix it

@cornelius - I am well aware of that, I approved it. Nevertheless, the original link worked without the need for the archive.org prefix. However, the arguments after the main URL were not required, hence my approval...

@Greenonline The link with the arguments led to a japanese 404 site for me. When I removed the arguments, it worked - but in any case, it's always better to use archive.org links imo - files are removed all the time.

It's just a source follower if you are just considering the voltage at the pyroelectric element. So the output will more-or-less follow the input (gain of about 1) with an offset voltage (positive, of course, since all JFETs are depletion mode) that depends on the resistor and JFET characteristics.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
However the pyroelectric element is going to behave more like a voltage source in series with a capacitor. The time constant will give you the behavior shown in Vir. And the light is going to be modulated by a Fresnel lens in most real motion detector applications.

And what of the resistor in parallel with the pyro-electric element, does that not affect the characteristics of the circuit?

That's the 'R' in the RC time constant I mentioned. The value of the 'C' and 'R' are not particularly important in modeling the behavior- only the product of the two.

What is providing the DC offset?

The Idss (zero-gate voltage drain current) has to be throttled back, which requires a negative gate-source voltage, so the source (output) will be more positive than the gate (input). If you picked too low a value of source resistor then that might not be possible and the circuit would not work properly.
